# Get typeguard guard type for HOF

Tags: typescript

I have the following simple HOF

```
function myHOF(input: any, typeguard: (thing: any) => boolean) {
  if (typeguard(input)) {
    return input;
  }
}
```

with the typeguard function

```
function myTypeguard(input: any): input is Array<any> {
  return Array.isArray(input);
}
```

Used as

```
const val = [1,2];
const thing = myHOF(val, myTypeguard);  // <- should be Array<any> | undefined
```

Clearly, this is oversimplified, but this type of thing becomes important in creating generic tree-traversal HOF's. Is there any compatibility in the language for this yet?

The more interesting example

```
export function* depthFirstRetrieval<T=PlanNode, L=PlanNode>(
  jxml: T,
  stopConditional: (obj: PlanNode) => boolean,
) {
  if (stopConditional(jxml)) {
    yield jxml;
  } else {
    for (const key of Object.keys(jxml) as Array<keyof typeof jxml>) {
      const property = jxml[key];
      if (Array.isArray(property)) {
        for (const childNode of property) {
          yield *depthFirstRetrieval(childNode, stopConditional);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should yield type `L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use a type guard signature in higher-order functions.  In fact, the [TypeScript standard library's type definition for `Array.filter()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1213) uses this to allow you to return a narrower array than the one you filter:

> `interface Array {
>     filter(
>       callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, 
>       thisArg?: any
>   ): S[];`

Anyway, for your example:

```
function myHOF<T>(input: any, typeguard: (thing: any) => thing is T) : T | undefined {
  if (typeguard(input)) {
    return input;
  }
  return;
}
```

The `myHOF()` is generic in `T` because you want to output the same type `T` that you test for with the type guard.  Also note how the `typeguard` parameter is annotated as a function returning the type predicate `thing is T`.

Now you can use it how you expect:

```
function myTypeguard(input: any): input is Array<any> {
  return Array.isArray(input);
}

const val = [1,2];
const thing = myHOF(val, myTypeguard);  // thing is any[] | undefined
```

---

Edit: I'm not 100% sure about your other case with `PlanNode`, but maybe this:

```
export function* depthFirstRetrieval<T extends PlanNode, L extends PlanNode>(
  jxml: T,
  stopConditional: (obj: PlanNode) => obj is L,
): IterableIterator<L>
{
  if (stopConditional(jxml)) {
    yield jxml;
  } else {
    for (const key of Object.keys(jxml) as Array<keyof typeof jxml>) {
      const property = jxml[key];
      if (Array.isArray(property)) {
        for (const childNode of property) {
          yield *depthFirstRetrieval(childNode, stopConditional);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Superb! This is exactly what I needed.